# React Native - Assign this.state.var to a variable

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, asynchronous, react-native

I need to pass the string "this.state.localita" to var "loc" for fetch data from JSON.

If I print this.state.localita i can read the string, but if I assign that to the var loc it's says JSON Unhandle promise.

```
componentDidMount() {
  AsyncStorage.getItem("localita").then((value) => {
      this.setState({"localita": value});
  }).done();
  this._refreshData();
}

_refreshData() {
  var loc = this.state.localita; // Here is the problem

  fetch('https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%20in%20(select%20woeid%20from%20geo.places(1)%20where%20text%3D%22' +
    loc +'%2C%20Italy%22)&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys')

  .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((rjson) => {
      this.setState({
        dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(rjson.query.results.channel.item.forecast)
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you bound `this` to `_refreshData()` in your `constructor`?

Comment: constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    var ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
    this.state = {
      dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows([])
    };
  }

Comment: You should do `this._refreshData = this._refreshData.bind(this);` because ES6 classes don't autobind.

Comment: additionally, you may want to refactor your functions, 1) call `this._refreshData(localita)` when `getItem` returns, and pass in the `localita ` as an argument.

Comment: @peterp I don't think `this` binding is an issue here. `this._refreshData()` is called directly from a `this`-bound method (`componentDidMount`) so doesn't need the extra context binding. The problem, as I see it, is that Fabio is expecting `this.state.localita` to have a value immediately, even though the thing that sets it is async.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that `this.state.localita` doesn't have a value at the time that you expect it to. The `AsyncStorage.get()` method is asynchronous, but you call `this._refreshData()` synchronously. As such, `AsyncStorage.get()` probably hasn't fired its accept promise by the time that you are querying `this.state.localita`.

What you really need to do is the following:

```
componentDidMount() {
    AsyncStorage.getItem("localita").then((value) => {
        this.setState(
            {"localita": value},
            this._refreshData.bind(this)
        );
    });
}

_refreshData() {
    var loc = this.state.localita; // Here is the problem

    if (! loc) {
        return
    }

    // fetch, etc...
}
```

This only calls setState once the AsyncStorage has the value you need, and then queues up a call to refreshData only after the state has been updated. We use `.bind(this)` here to ensure that the method knows about `this` correctly, as passing a function reference as a callback loses the `this` context.